# Android Studio Can't Emulate A Device With Opengl ES 3.2

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I'm trying to emulate the .apk of my game through Android Studio's AVD, developed and packaged with Unreal Engine 5.1, which requires Opengl ES 3.2. But when creating emulated devices, only options are 2.0. I'm on a Windows (10) system, and have the latest drivers, verified my opengl version with Opengl Extensions Viewer (it was 4.6). What do I need to do to have emulated devices with Opengl ES 3.2? I have Android Studio 4.0, which is the version that Unreal Engine 5.1 is compatible with. So I can't change it. Do I need one version of Android Studio for building and another version for emulating, that seems like a pain in the ass.